# Multi alarms fire at same time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have two issues my friends. 
The first issue I have set multi alarms but when I launch the app they all starts at same time even it's not the time 
By the way I'm using object in project here is my code :

Main Fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_liste_alarme, container, false);
    final ProgrammeBDD programmeBDD = new ProgrammeBDD(getActivity());
    lvProgrammes = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvprogrammes);
    programmeBDD.open();
    //programmeBDD.insertProgramme(new Programme("Medii1", "03:15", "0111000", 1, 1, 1));

    programmeList = programmeBDD.getAllProgramme();
    Collections.sort(programmeList);
    adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), programmeList);
    lvProgrammes.setAdapter(adapter);
    setAlarm();
    programmeBDD.close();
    return view;
}
```

setAlarm() method :

```
private void setAlarm() {
    alarmManager = new AlarmManager[programmeList.size()];
    intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    for (int i = 0; i < programmeList.size(); i++) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("IdProgramme", programmeList.get(i).getId());
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), i, intent, 0);
        alarmManager[i] = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager[i].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, toCalendar(programmeList.get(i).getDateTime()).getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        intentArray.add(pi);
    }
}
```

My Receiver class :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Your Time is up!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Vibrator vib=(Vibrator)context.getSystemService(context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    //for Vibration
    vib.vibrate(2000);

    Intent i=new Intent(context,AlarmReceiverActivity.class);  //song class contain media song
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("IdProgramme",0);
    i.putExtra("IdProgramme", id);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
}
```

The second issue, is that I what each alarm of them repeat after a specific different time from it fire.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Purpose behind this - `alarmManager = new AlarmManager[programmeList.size()];` ?

Comment: Is to instance alarmManager object and give him the same size of my alarms that I want to set

Comment: There is no meaning of creating multiple instance, and `AlarmManager` must be initialized like - `alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);`

Comment: No Sir it s not a multiple instance, because alarmManager that is a array of alarmManager ( AlarmManager [] alarmManager )
And the initialized that You said it's already there down look up

Comment: Still, `AlarmManager` is initialized in for loop. One instance could be enough. and if the time that you are setting has been already passed, alarm will be triggered immediately.

Answer (score 1):

**ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP examples**
Here are some examples of using ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP.

Wake up the device to fire the alarm in 30 minutes, and every 30 minutes after that:

```
// Hopefully your alarm will have a lower frequency than this!
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
```

Wake up the device to fire a one-time (non-repeating) alarm in one minute:

```
  private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
  private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
  ...
  alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
  alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

  alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
    60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

**RTC examples**
Here are some examples of using RTC_WAKEUP.

Wake up the device to fire the alarm at approximately 2:00 p.m., and repeat once a day at the same time:

```
 // Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

 // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
 // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
 alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,          calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Wake up the device to fire the alarm at precisely 8:30 a.m., and every 20 minutes thereafter:

```
  private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
  private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
  ...
  alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
  alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

  // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

  // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
 // 20 minutes.
 alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Thank You Dream for your correction and your answer about repeating,

Comment: What about first issue ? that after I launch the app all alarms starts

Comment: you start all at same time ? i think if u start individually at different time it works.

Comment: Sorry how is that, cuz I have in my database my objects and each object has a specific time so when I read all objects in arraylist I made multi alarms but like I said they all start after launch even they have diffrent time @DreamCoder

Comment: try using individual create Alarm for just check